# Error message in R during export of a panel dataset to a CSV file

Tags: r, csv, export, panel-data

I am currently trying to export a panel dataset in R to a CSV file. When exporting I receive the following error message in R:

```
Error in `is.data.frame()`:
! Can't recycle `value` (size 6) to size 4.
Backtrace:
  1. utils::write.csv(merge_long, "Merge_Long.csv")
  5. utils::write.table(...)
 14. tibble:::`[<-.tbl_df`(`*tmp*`, needconv, value = `<named list>`)
```

After the supposed export, I receive an empty CSV file in my Explorer.

I once displayed which data object my panel dataset "Merge-Long" has. Unfortunately, I no longer know what I can/should do.

```
> class(merge_long)
[1] "panel_data" "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Comment: a couple of questions: 1. can you create a new df, head_df, by doing `head_df <- head(merge_long)`, and check if it fails for head_df too? If yes, run dput() on it, and edit your question to add the output to it. 2. Try using readr::write_csv() instead

Comment: Hi Mark, readr::write_csv() works! Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm guessing what happened was, your dataframe contained list columns, or perhaps columns which themselves contained dataframes, and the base R write.csv() didn't like that

Comment: though it could be that your data is of the class panel_data, and/or is a grouped df

Comment: hard to say without experimenting with the data